# error with pg_restore while creating default acl

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pg-restore, pg-repack

got this error when doing a pg_restore. dump & restore are done using same master account in both source/target. I see its related to pg_repack, but cannot figure out why this error is happening during restore. Please advise

```
pg_restore: creating DEFAULT ACL "repack.DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR SEQUENCES"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 3204; 826 24360292 DEFAULT ACL DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR SEQUENCES rdsadmin
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  must be member of role "rdsadmin"
    Command was: ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE rdsadmin IN SCHEMA repack GRANT SELECT,USAGE ON SEQUENCES  TO rds_superuser;

pg_restore: creating DEFAULT ACL "repack.DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR TABLES"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 3203; 826 24360291 DEFAULT ACL DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR TABLES rdsadmin
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  must be member of role "rdsadmin"
    Command was: ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE rdsadmin IN SCHEMA repack GRANT INSERT ON TABLES  TO rds_superuser;
```

Postgres 11.13

Should i drop this extension and recreate in target?

Comment: Ask Amazon - they did that. This is not about PostgreSQL.